# How to remove specific legends in ggplot2?

Tags: ggplot2, legend

I have three groups (Tissue) and two groups (Treatment) represented in a faceted [boxplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHAac.png). I would like to remove the legend for "Treatment", as it is already represented in the graph, and keep the legend for "Tissue".

```
box <- ggboxplot(subclusDF, 
                 x = 'Treatment', 
                 y = 'ATP4',
                 fill = "Tissue", 
                 color = 'Tissue', 
                 palette = qualitative_hcl(3, palette = 'Dark 3'),
                 add = 'jitter', 
                 shape = 'Treatment')
box <- box + 
    labs(title= 'GHRL') + 
    xlab(NULL) + 
    ylab("Expression") + 
    facet_grid(~Tissue)
box

box + 
  theme() +
  theme(
    plot.title = element_text(face = "bold", size = 12),
    legend.background = element_rect(fill = "white", size = 4, colour = "white"),
    legend.justification = c(0, 1),
    legend.title=element_text(NULL),
    legend.key = element_blank(),
    legend.position = c(0, 1),
    axis.text = (NULL),
    axis.ticks = element_line(colour = "grey70", size = 0.2),
    panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "grey70", size = 0.2),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank()
  )
box
```

Comment: It would be good to include your code so we can give you specific feedback. Edit: check the [cookbook](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Legends_(ggplot2)/#removing-the-legend).

Comment: Thanks for that, I want to specially remove one legend and not the other, so not sure the cookbook handles that, but will look again

Comment: You can try `+ scale_shape_discrete(guide = "none")`, but this is an untested guess because I cannot reproduce the issue. Or `+ guides(shape = "none")`.

Answer (score 1):

So, specifically you'd want to remove the legend for shape:

```
box + 
guides(shape = "none")
```

Comment: Just wanted to let you know, this code gives the following error:    
  The `<scale>` argument of `guides()` cannot be `FALSE`. Use "none" instead as of
  ggplot2 3.3.4.    
Instead this works:   guides(shape = "none")